# Create image in R from a data frame of hex color strings

Tags: r, image

I have a data frame of hex colors that I want to plot in R as an image. In this example, there are 10 rows each containing 6 pixels from left to right. Clearly, `image(df)` won't work because image needs a matrix, and `image(as.matrix(df))` won't work because it's expecting pixel intensities. I also tried creating a matrix of 1's, and then trying

```
m <- matrix(data=1, nrow=10, ncol=6)
image(m, col=df)
```

I then tried to use the `htmlTable` package, like this:

```
htmlTable(m, color = paste0("background-color:", df))
```

and also tried to unsuccessfully `as.matrix(df)` just in case. Does anyone know a straightforward way to create an image out of an R data frame of hex colors? Thanks in advance.

Here is the dput:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#c5dff8", "#c5dff8", 
"#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#cccccc", "#cccccc"
), col2 = c("#c5dff8", "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", 
"#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#cccccc"), col3 = c("#c5dff8", 
"#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", 
"#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#7895cb"), col4 = c("#c5dff8", "#cccccc", 
"#cccccc", "#c5dff8", "#a0bfe0", "#a0bfe0", "#a0bfe0", "#7895cb", 
"#cccccc", "#cccccc"), col5 = c("#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", 
"#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", 
"#7895cb"), col6 = c("#c5dff8", "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", 
"#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#cccccc", "#cccccc"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are looking for this results?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
      ~col1,     ~col2,     ~col3,     ~col4,     ~col5,     ~col6,
  "#cccccc", "#c5dff8", "#c5dff8", "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#c5dff8",
  "#cccccc", "#c5dff8", "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#c5dff8",
  "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc",
  "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#c5dff8", "#cccccc", "#cccccc",
  "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc",
  "#a0bfe0", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0",
  "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#a0bfe0", "#a0bfe0", "#a0bfe0", "#cccccc",
  "#7895cb", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#cccccc", "#7895cb",
  "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#7895cb", "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#cccccc",
  "#cccccc", "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#cccccc", "#7895cb", "#cccccc"
  )


df |>
  rowid_to_column("x") |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -x, names_to = "y", values_to = "color") |>
  mutate(y = parse_number(y)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = color)) +
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Johan, this got me where I needed to get! The colors were not coming out right, but after trial and error, adding `scale_fill_identity() +` after `geom_tile()` did the trick.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally forgot about that. I'm adding that to the answer.